# How to load CSS background images in to admin section

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to create a Gutenberg version of my site, and obviously I want the backend editor to show the same view as on the frontend. So .. I have two stylesheets, both put in the theme root (and referenced the right way in functions.php (and they are working correctly)

1. A frontend sass file (styles.scss)
2. and a backend sass file (editor-styles.scss)

In both sass files I am including a scss partial called _elements.scss, where I (among other things) insert some custom bullet points for a list:

```
.default-checklist-item {  //this is a <li> element
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 4.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  text-align: left;

  &:before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url('icons/custom/checkmark-round.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    fill: green;
  }
}
```

So both stylesheets will pull the background-image from the same relative path, but obviously the bullets won't show in the editor, becasue the file path here is attached to the https://example.com/wp-admin/ path:

1. On frontend, the file displays correctly
2. In the editor the file (obviously) can't be found at https://example.com/wp-admin/

I really desire to make use of the same style partial, so only have to maintain it one place, and absolute paths are impossible, since I work on both local, staging and live environments, so what to do??

Comment: what's your folder structure?

Comment: Wordpress default... As explained the stylesheets are located in the theme root. The svg image file I want to pull is inside the  theme root> icons > custom folder. The partial is included from an assets folder but it is loaded correctly in to both sass files

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts' , function () {

    wp_register_style( 'admin-checklist-handle' , false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-checklist-handle' );

    wp_add_inline_style( 'admin-checklist-handle' , '.default-checklist-item:before { background-image: url( "' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/icons/custom/checkmark-round.svg" )!important; }' );

} );
```

This should add an inline style element in the admin view. And that should override your default pseudo-element. (untested though)